# Facebook Open Graph : permissions for user actions

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am trying to have my app reading a user's actions within the application.

I was trying to apply what is stated in this document : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/permissions/

If I do graph/userid/namespace:action with my userid and my user token, it works.
When I try with my application token it returns an empty array.

I used the following permissions for the app, but never see them appear in the dialog :
 user_actions:pimsrecipebox
It doens't appear in the app settings in my user profile.
I tried with user_actions.music and that worked.

I have searched all over the web without success :(

Is it a beta feature ?

Update : I tried to get an action with my app token, nothing, while I can see it with my user token.

Do my actions have to be approved ?